# Ошибка: Индекс находился вне границ массива C#

Tags: c#

```
string reverse(string s) {
    int x = s.Length;
    char[] s1 = s.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < x/2; i++) {
        char tmp;
        tmp = s1[x - i];
        s1[x] = s[i];
        s1[i] = tmp;
    }
    s = new string(s1);
    return s;
}
```

Выдает ошибку на: tmp = s1[x - i];

Comment: `tmp = s1[x - i];` - к какому элементу массива обращается код, когда `i` равнo нулю?

Comment: Следующая ошибка будет в следующей строчке (.

Comment: `int x = s.Length;` ==> `int x = s.Length-1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ошибка сама говорит о том, куда нужно смотреть.
2. `s.Length` вернет длину строки.

   Однако, массивы индексируются с 0=> от полученного результата нужно
   вычесть 1.

   Соответственно, уже на первой итерации цикла вы получаете ошибку,
   что находитесь за пределами.